# how to binding something to groupstyle's header

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Using CollectionViewSource can easily grouping the ListBoxItem.
But each group Header, only have a "Name" data. 
How to put more data to the Header?

like the picture.

1. i want to use a custom control in the header, and binding a viewmodel to it.
   but i dont know how to get the viewmodel from the grouping parent.
2. and, the `<ItemsPresenter/>`, groupItem's part.if i want binding something to it, 
   what can i do?

and , my code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XamlBookMarks}}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateBookMark}">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource StyleBookMarkGroup}" />
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
</ListBox>

 <Style x:Key="StyleWorkSiteGroup" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateHeader}" />
                        <!--here, i want binding something to ItemsPresenter-->
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

     <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateHeader" DataType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <DockPanel>
            <DockPanel.Resources>
                <converters:HeaderGetter x:Key="HeaderConverter" />
            </DockPanel.Resources>
            <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource HeaderConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource XamlHeaders}}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupOneHeaderViewModel}">
                        <views:GroupOneHeaderView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupTwoHeaderViewModel}">
                        <views:GroupTwoHeaderView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

[image]

Comment: You can just override the `Group` style to add whatever you need

Comment: @sa_ddam213 thank you,i edited my question, and what i need is ,how could i get viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I made a wrapper class , but feel very ugly . Is there any other way to do this ?

**1,get the Transition class from**

> http://www.11011.net/wpf-transitions

**2.and**

```
public class GroupItemsSelector : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source",
                                    typeof (CollectionViewSource),
                                    typeof (GroupItemsSelector),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(OnSourceChangedCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Id",
                                    typeof (string),
                                    typeof (GroupItemsSelector),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(OnSourceChangedCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Current",
                                    typeof (object),
                                    typeof (GroupItemsSelector),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(OnCurrentItemChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WatchingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Watching",
                                    typeof (string),
                                    typeof (GroupItemsSelector),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(OnCurrentItemChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WatchingValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WatchingValue",
                                    typeof (object),
                                    typeof (GroupItemsSelector));

    private readonly Transition _transition = new Transition();

    public GroupItemsSelector()
    {
        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Transition.StateProperty, typeof (Transition));
        if (dpd == null) return;
        dpd.AddValueChanged(_transition, delegate { WatchingValue = _transition.Source; });
    }

    public object WatchingValue
    {
        get { return GetValue(WatchingValueProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(WatchingValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Watching
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(WatchingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WatchingProperty, value); }
    }

    public CollectionViewSource Source
    {
        get { return (CollectionViewSource) GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(IdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IdProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get { return GetValue(CurrentProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(CurrentProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnCurrentItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = d as GroupItemsSelector;
        if (selector == null) return;
        selector.SetWatchingProperty();
    }

    private static void OnSourceChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = d as GroupItemsSelector;
        if (selector == null) return;
        selector.SetCurrent();
    }

    private void SetCurrent()
    {
        IDictionary dictionary = null;
        bool hasValue = false;
        try
        {
            if (Source == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id)) return;
            dictionary = Source.Source as IDictionary;
            if (dictionary == null) return;
            hasValue = dictionary.Contains(Id);
        }
        finally
        {
            Current = (hasValue) ? dictionary[Id] : null;
        }
    }

    private void SetWatchingProperty()
    {
        _transition.DataContext = Current as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Watching))
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(_transition, Transition.SourceProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            _transition.SetBinding(Transition.SourceProperty, new Binding(Watching));
        }
    }
}
```

**3. and sample**

```
<Style x:Key="StyleGroupItem" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <converters:GroupItemsSelector x:Name="selector" Id="{Binding Name}" Source="{StaticResource XamlHeaders}" Watching="IsExpanded"/>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=selector, Path=Current}" >                                
                            </ContentControl>
                            <ItemsPresenter Visibility="{Binding ElementName=selector, Path=WatchingValue, Converter={x:Static converters:BoolVisiblilityConverter.Instance}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```